# how to limit number httpd process for port 80

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, port

So lets say I have 10 instances of `httpd` on port 80 and another 10 on 443.

I run everything through 443, so I don't see the need to balance the connections (80 is used only to redirect to 443)

How do I reduce port 80 to 5 instances and increase port 443 to 15?

What regulates the number of process? (I find info on controlling `connections`, none on this, or I don't know what to search for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into what settings you're using - the MPM you're configured for and the settings for that MPM are what control this.

But, what you're going for (different capacities for 80 and 443) isn't possible, at least not without running two completely separate Apache services (which will easily eliminate any efficiency gains you were hoping for by limiting port 80).

I suspect you're not coming at your problem in the best way - can you clarify what problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Just trying to direct more resources to 443 since I didn't need 80 anymore (only used to redirect to 443), it's more of a learning question, above when you say `service` is that the same as a `process`?

Comment: @PrivatMamtora Well, simply sending a redirect response requires almost no resources, so unless you're getting a boatload of requests against port 80 (say, from a bot not following the redirect) then you don't need to worry.  A separate service would be a very different thing from allocation of worker processes - a new service would mean a separate config, a separate systemd unit file, and splitting all of that up by hand since the CentOS package assumes you only want to run one Apache.

Comment: I had 6 `httpd` process listening on port `80` so I thought I could simply tune it down to 2 or 3. So I guess this falls under unnecessary optimization?